# Add Function to new Column by Row Value using Vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a Pandas DataFrame with many columns and I need to take the part number column and use the data in it to populate the features column. My function **add_data** takes the part number and looks it up in a SQL database and returns the feature notes.

I have this working with **df.apply** and it works well
(code block 1).

Because I recently started learning vectorization and was wondering if there was a way to do this without df.apply(code block 2)

```
#Working Code
df['Features'] = df.apply (lambda row: add_data(row['partnumber']), axis=1)

def add_data(row):
        featurenotes = sql_lookup(row)
        return featurenotes
```

This line of code calls my add_data function but I don't know how to grab just the value of the row in the part number column to use in my function.

```
df['Features'] = add_data(df['partnumber'])
```

I'm am very new to python so I am trying to learn best practices and how to manipulate pandas DataFrames.

Comment: vectorization on SQL calls? You may want to read on [`async/await`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

Comment: From what I understand vectorization is a way to evaluate a function on each element simultaneously, I wouldn't think the contents of the function would matter.